# Trasforming pixel art into ASCII art

Tags: python, hex

I am trying to do something difficult because I'm a bit insane. I am making a text/ASCII adventure game in python for my introduction to programing class. I have a few of the systems I will be using made already but I want to make sure I can create new content as needed in a relatively short time.

One of the key features of this game will be its battle maps. Using ASCII symbols to represent terrain and peaces on a board (kinda like DND) I can make several 15x10 maps. However I find that creating these maps is time consuming and annoying. Something I want to do is take an image like the one I hope I managed to attach and look at its hex code in python. From there have a script that looks at each colored pixel and put a ASCII character into that same spot on a text file.

The goal is to get the image attached(This example is made larger and the white pixels have been darkened) to look something like the following.
[An image of several colored pixels with a white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmK7O.png)

```
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|▒
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|▓
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|@
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|¥
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|E
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|w
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|s
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|z
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░
```

I know this isn't going to be easy but I just need a break down / guidance of two things.

1. What is the make up of an image when looking at it in a HEX editor
   HEX of the attached image

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 0A 08 06 00 00 00 6B 1B 04 F9 00 00 00 40 49 44 41 54 28 53 63 FC 0F 04 0C 64 02 46 72 35 6F DD BA 95 81 6C CD EE EE EE E4 6B 2E 30 9A 49 BE 66 E5 4D BE E4 6B 9E C5 68 48 81 E6 5B AF C9 D7 CC B8 E3 03 F9 9A FD F2 BE 90 AF 19 94 AE 00 38 F2 33 B8 0F CC E8 54 00 00 00 00 49 45 4E 44 AE 42 60 82
```

2. What resources python has to read these types of files.

I am aware that python can use the open(), write(), and read() functions to make it possible to look at the file as well as edit files. It's easy with text files and I've been doing that alot with this being an RPG I'm making. Lots of dialog and stats to keep track of.

Comment: You can't directly read an image with open() and expect it to be a (H, W, C) matrix where each HEX value represent the pixel value of the image Channel. Why? Because images usually have headers, metadata, are compressed or whatever... But you can do it with specific libraries like Pillow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PIL](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) library to read image pixel-by-pixel and then convert it to ASCII art:

```
from PIL import Image

ITEMS = {(194, 194, 194, 255): '░',
         (180, 180, 180, 255): '▒',
         (70, 70, 70, 255): '▓',
         (111, 49, 152, 255): '@',
         (34, 177, 76, 255): '¥',
         (153, 0, 48, 255): 'E',
         (153, 217, 234, 255): 'w',
         (0, 183, 239, 255): 's',
         (77, 109, 243, 255): 'z'}

image = Image.open('image.png')
width, height = image.size
pix = image.load()
for y in range(0, height, 50):
    line = ''
    for x in range(0, width, 50):
        line += ITEMS[pix[x, y]] + '|'
    print(line[:-1])
```

Output:

```
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|▒
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|▓
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|@
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|¥
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|E
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|w
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|s
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|z
░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░|░
```